Built-in observability capabilitis in WSO2 Micro Integrator
I am using WSO2 Micro Integrator (mi) 4.2 and for the sake of Application Perf. Monitoring (APM), I need to export the following:

Metrics of the JVM running the wso2 mi 4.2 application.

The diagnostic logs that are typically written to the wso2carbon.log file.


For testing the observability features, I am running wso2 mi 4.2 on the bare-metal host OS. Eventually, it will be running in a Kubernetes environment (as a pod).
I followed the instructions provided in the page OpenTelemetry Configurations for MI i.e. entries in the deployment.toml file. But, I don't neither see the trace  messages in the wso2carbon-trace-messages.log or wso2-mi-open-telemetry.log files,nor do I see any data sent to the OTLP endpoint (Grafana Loki in my case).

Question 1: In addition to the steps provided in the link above, do I need to do anything else ?

Question 2: Other than exporting the runtime logs using fluentbit, are there any other recommended ways of sending the logs to the log store ?


I followed the instructions provided in the page OpenTelemetry Configurations for MI i.e. entries in the deployment.toml file. But, I don't neither see the trace  messages in the wso2carbon-trace-messages.log or wso2-mi-open-telemetry.log files,nor do I see any data sent to the OTLP endpoint (Grafana Loki in my case).
I was expecting wso2 mi to send the logs to the OTLP endpoint provided.

Question 1: In addition to the steps provided in the link above, do I need to do anything else ?
If you enable Log Tracing, you will see tracing data generated in the <MI_HOME>/repository/logs/wso2-mi-open-telemetry.log file. Since you're running on a Kubernetes environment, could there be problems with your file mounts, if any?
If you are configuring an OTLP Endpoint, you'll have to provide the appropriate endpoint URL. Could you please show your configurations on how are you configuring the endpoint URL for Loki/Grafana?
Question 2: Other than exporting the runtime logs using fluentbit, are there any other recommended ways of sending the logs to the log store ?
Any log based analytics solution such as Filebeats + ELK or Fluentbit should be fine.
